# Название таблицы в результате запроса SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте, имеется две таблицы, нужно вывести все поля обоих таблиц, и поле с названием таблицы из которой взята строка. Попробую объяснить наглядно:

```
table1:
    ---------------------
    | id | page | data1 |
    ---------------------

teble2:
    -----------------------------
    | id | page | data2 | data3 |
    -----------------------------

SELECT '@' FROM table1, table2 WHERE page=3

result:
    --------------------------------------------------
    | tablename | id | page | data1 | data2 | data3  |
    --------------------------------------------------
    |  table1   | 3  |  3   | test  |       |        |
    |  table1   | 5  |  3   | t     |       |        |
    |  table2   | 2  |  3   |       |  g13  | others |
    |  table2   | 3  |  3   |       |  a1   | false  |   
    --------------------------------------------------
```

Какую конструкцию использовать на месте '@' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from (
select 'table1' as tablename, id, page, data1, null as data2, null as data3 from table1
union all
select 'table2' as tablename, id, page, null as data1, data2, data3 from table2
) X where page = 3
```

Comment: чего то тут не хватает вроде бы

Comment: да, from table1 и from table2 не хватает. а так все верно.

Comment: Добавил. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1, table2
```

Comment: кто-нибудь, поставте минус за это )

Comment: А сами что не ставите?